# Adding relation to base entity (inheritance)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, database-design

I have 3 transmission types. Two of them holds details of worker and vehicle. I need to represent those entities in the entity framework. So I created base entity called Transmission that holds common tramsission properties. Then I created 3 other specific entities for the three transmission types: Transmission1, Transmission2 and Transmission3.
The primary key of Tramsission is referenced by the primary key of each transmission type.

I loaded all the 4 entities to the edmx and create inheritance: Transmission is parent of Transmission1, Transmission2 and Transmission3.

Now I want to encapsulate the worker and vehicle data that exists in Transmission1 and Transmission2. So I created WorkerVehicle entity that has id of transmission and the worker/vehicle properties.

Now, when I load WorkerVehicle to the edmx, I get relation between WorkerVehicle and Transmission entities where what I really want is a relation between WorkerVehicle and Transmission1/Transmission2.

How can I fix this?
Shold I leave the relation between WorkerVehicle to Transmission and allow Transmission3 store WorkerVehicle data?

**UPDATE**
Here is an image that describes the situation:
[image]

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of the edmx design and point out what you want different than shown in the diagram?

Comment: @Chris: My real world situation is more complex and contains 9 transmission types and a lot of data. I will try to add something that will not complicate all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't unless you refactor your model and create some intermediate base class derived from `Transmission` which will be parent of `Container` classes. After that you can try to form relation with that class. Moving relations to derived class in EDMX is usually clumsy and you can end with modifying EDMX manually.